# Alternative to "impactful" when referring to work with meaningful effect on peoples' lives

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I had a little bit of space left on my CV and so decided to add a very brief overview of my background and what I'm looking for.

One of the sentences mentions something like, "... interesting, impactful part-time work."

Now, I don't like the word "impactful" as it's too vague. I'm looking for 1 or 2 words to describe work that has a meaningful, almost measurable positive effect on the organization.

Any tips or advice?

Comment: How about "managerial" part-time work?

Comment: "Constructive" perhaps.  Whatever you do, don't say "almost measurable positive effect" - this kind of implies that the work had no real effect.

Comment: Why not a word you used in your question? "... interesting, *meaningful* part-time work."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While not exactly the same as *impactful*, perhaps [purposeful](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/purposeful) will be a good fit. "Purposeful work" is [consistently used](https://www.google.com/search?q=purposeful+work&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=1&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22purposeful+work%22&oq=%22purposeful+work%22&gs_l=serp.3...2334.3005.0.3214.2.2.0.0.0.0.146.281.0j2.2.0...0.0...1c.tx-wBiFi9Q4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=182d50f29001f36a&biw=1280&bih=923) to convey a similar intent. For example,

> When we look into the detailed biographies of our ten talented people, there is one feature that stands out more than any other - *purposeful work*. These people set themselves objectives which they cherish as supremely ...

> Innovation occurs from hard, focused, and *purposeful work* demanding persistence, diligence, and commitment.

Answer (score 3):

Significant, relevant, inspiring, influencing or influential.

I understand you refer more to the attitude in the job than the job itself, which is supposed to be as relevant as your salary, so your attitude had some influence on the organization and not only your job.

Otherwise if you mean you did your job well, but did also care about the organization and not only your piece of work you could say that you were responsible, creative, proactive (very popular buzzword nowadays), etc.

Those are my best guesses.

Answer (score 0):

*... interesting **and positively effective*** might convey in the sense of having contributed usefully.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, it could also be 'fruitful'.

Answer (score 0):

Forward-facing, mission critical, high-impact, high visibility